# Connecting two different database in wordpress for search query

Tags: database, wordpress, search

I have two databases in same server.

I want to show single result from two different databases when user search any term.

say for example, if user searches my site for "rent house" then result should display continuous single result from two different databases.

can anyone guide me please ?

I am using wordpress.

Comment: Are they both WordPress databases? Same server? Same user can access both?

Comment: yes both are wordpress databases. both are on same server and same user also. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you need to process the data at the server before displaying it.

Comment: your answer should have codings, rather than help  text or link